# Aussprache des Worts "Furcht"

Tags: pronunciation

Bin mir nicht sicher, wie man das Wort 'Furcht' korrekt ausspricht. Wird bei dem Wort das 'r' gesprochen? Soll das so was wie 'Fu-richt' ausgesprochen werden? Hörbeispiele helfen nicht viel.

Comment: Ich bin (vielleicht wie du?) englischer Muttersprachler, und das Wort hört sich für mich oft etwas wie "Feucht" an (also ich höre fast denselben Laut, der im Wort "Deutsch" vorkommt). Genauso wie in "durch."

Comment: Du hast auch gesagt, dass Hörbeispiele nicht helfen, aber hast du diese Website entdeckt? https://youglish.com/pronounce/furcht/german?

Answer (score 6):

Wie das "r" ausgesprochen wird, ist regional sehr unterschiedlich. Ein gerolltes "r" ist genauso akzeptabel wie ein Schwa-Laut, wie er in "Bär" oder "nur" in vielen Regionen vorkommt.

Es sollte auf keinen Fall wie "Furicht" ausgesprochen werden. Das Wort hat definitiv nur eine Silbe und keinen "i"-Vokal irgendwo im Wort.

Comment: Auch nicht 'Fu-icht?'? Das "r" kann ich jedenfalls nicht hören...

Comment: In vielen Gegenden des deutschsprachigen Raums wird das r in <Vokal>-r-Kombinationen (ar, er, ur etc.) nicht als solches ausgesprochen, sondern eher wie ein a oder ein Schwa (unbetontes e); siehe auch die Hinweise in [Huberts Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73750/10959)

Answer (score 5):

Dieses Wort hat keine Besonderheiten bei der Aussprache. Insbesondere kommt zwischen dem R und dem CH kein Vokal vor. Die beiden Buchstaben *ch* werden als ein Laut [ç] ausgesprochen, das ist derselbe Laut, der am Ende von *»ich«* vorkommt. Alle anderen Buchstaben werden als jeweils ein Laut ausgesprochen. In allen Fällen ist das der normale Standard-Laut für den jeweiligen Buchstaben bzw. für das Digramm:

- F = [f]
- u = [ʊ]
- r = [r] oder [ʀ] oder [ʁ]
- ch = [ç]
- t = [t]

Aussprache des ganzen Wortes: [fʊʁçt]

Die letzen 4 Buchstaben ergeben also einen Konsonantencluster, der aus 3 Lauten besteht. Solche Konsonantencluster sind im Deutschen sehr häufig. (Das einsilbige Wort *»Strumpf«* ist ein schönes Beispiel dafür.)

Die drei Laute [r], [ʀ] und [ʁ] sind in der deutschen Sprache Allophone, also Laute, die zwar unterschiedlich klingen, aber beliebig ausgetauscht werden dürfen, ohne dass es dadurch zu Verständigungsschwierigkeiten kommt. In unterschiedlichen geographischen Regionen werden unterschiedliche Laute für den Buchstaben R bevorzugt, aber alle drei Laute werden überall verstanden.

Sehr oft wird der Buchstabe R, wenn er direkt auf einen Vokal folgt, auch selbst als Vokal ausgesprochen:

- nur = [nuːɐ̯]

Daher findet man in einigen Regionen auch diese Aussprache:

- Furcht = [fʊɐ̯çt]

Vergleiche:

- eingepfercht = [ˈaɪ̯nɡəˌp͡fɛʁçt] oder [ˈaɪ̯nɡəˌp͡fɛɐ̯çt]
- horcht = [hɔʁçt] oder [hɔɐ̯çt]
- fürchten = [ˈfʏʁçtn̩] oder [ˈfʏɐ̯çtn̩]
- kirchlich =  [ˈkɪʁçlɪç] oder [ˈkɪɐ̯çlɪç]

Auf Wikipedia gibt es eine [Liste der IPA-Zeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen), in der die Lautschrift genau erklärt ist. Dort gibt es auch weiterführende Links, in denen die einzelnen laute genauer erklärt werden.

Comment: Der Laut am Ende von "ach" ist ein [x], nicht das [ç], das in Furcht vorkommt. Die anderen Beispiele unter "Vergleich" stimmen alle. Vielleicht meintest du "ich"?

Comment: @HalvarF Ich weiß nicht, an welchen Dialekt du denkst, aber ich (aus Ostösterreich) spreche "Furcht" mit einem ach-Laut aus.

Comment: @wonderbear Das glaube ich sofort, aus Bayern kenne ich das auch. Im Hochdeutschen wird "Furcht" mit dem Laut aus "ich" ausgesprochen, und der wird in der IPA mit [ç] notiert, der Laut aus "ach" wäre [x]. Siehe auch DWDS und Wiktionary. Hubert schreibt ja auch überall von [ç], und auch seine "Vergleiche" werden alle mit [ç] ausgesprochen, nur das Beispiel "ach" stimmt halt nicht.

Comment: Ich habe es jetzt mal korrigiert (jetzt "ich" statt vorher "ach"), weil [ç] tatsächlich das ich-CH ist, und das ach-CH mit dem Symbol [x] geschrieben wird. Aber ich bin nicht ganz davon überzeugt, dass *Furcht* tatsächlich mit [ç] gesprochen wird (zumindest im Osten Österreichs), auch wenn in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Furcht) und [theFreeDictionary](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/Furcht) ein [ç] steht. Mit theFreeDictionary habe ich wenig Erfahrung, aber in Wiktionary sind Fehler sehr rar, was in mir große Zweifel schürt. Aber ich höre in *Furcht* nicht ...

Comment: ... das ich-CH sondern das ach-CH. Ich habe beim Schreiben einfach die Lautschrift aller Beispiele aus Wiktionary hierher kopiert, und bin dabei irrtümlich davon ausgegangen, dass das Zeichen [ç] das ach-CH ist. Ich werde noch heute eine separate Frage zur Aussprache von CH in der Folge "urch" schreiben. Wir müssen das also nicht hier in den Kommentaren diskutieren. Weil ich heute aber auch andere Dinge zu tun habe, kann es ein paar Stunden dauern, bis ich die Frage fertig habe. Ich bitte so lange um Geduld.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Für mich ist ein wichtiges Erkennungsmerkmal für Sprecher aus der Region von Österreichisch/Bairisch, dass sie nach "r" "ch" wie in [x] statt wie der Rest Deutschlands mit [ç] sprechen. Ich dachte, dieser Unterschied wäre weithin bekannt.

Comment: Es hat zwar einen ganzen Tag gedauert, bis ich Zeit dafür gefunden habe, aber hier ist die angekündigte Frage: [Aussprache von CH nach R (durch, Arche, Kirche, ...)](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/73779/1487)

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt verschiedene Varianten. Die einfachste ist, es wie das Wort *Fur|che* auszusprechen, aber mit *t* statt *e* am Ende. Das *r* wird dabei zum Tiefschwa, und das *ch* ist dasselbe wie nach Konsonanten.

In den südlichen Mundarten ist es hingegen auch üblich, dasselbe *ch* wie nach den dunklen Vokalen *a*, *u*, *o* zu verwenden.

Answer (score 4):

Dank @cruthers' wunderbarem Link im Kommentar zur Frage kann man sich davon überzeugen, dass *Furcht* - vermutlich aus Gründen artikulatorischer Verschleifung - sich sehr häufig wie *fuicht* (mit kurzem, dunklem i, also wie [fʊɪçt] anhört. Eine Vokalisierung von **r** ist im Deutschen ja alles andere als unbekannt, und die Zungenstellung beim Laut [ç] hinter einem vokalisierten **r** liegt nahe bei der Zungenstellung von [ɪ]. @Hubert interpretiert das in meinen Augen richtigerweise als (intendiertes, angestrebtes) [fʊɐ̯çt], denn es ist kaum möglich vom **[ɐ̯]** zum **[ç]** zu kommen, ohne durchgangsweise ein **[ɪ]** mit der Zunge zu formen.

Ich frage mich schon lange, ob es neben ich- und ach-Laut nicht noch weitere **ch**-Aussprachen gibt. Der ach-Laut ist klar uvular (zäpfchen-erzeugt), den ich-Laut erzeuge ich einigermaßen palatal mit Tendenz zum Vordergaumen, aber bei z.B. "Buch" spreche ich oft weder einen ich- noch einen ach-Laut, sondern einen praktisch velaren, ziemlich weit hinten liegenden Laut, ich würde ihn **uuch-Laut** nennen. Die Norm hat dafür wohl den ach-Laut vorgesehen. Aussprachebeispiele gibt's [hier](https://youglish.com/pronounce/Buch/german?) en masse, ich kann dieses **uuch** und den ach-Laut in ***Buch*** akustisch nicht klar unterscheiden, weiß aber, dass es sich bei mir um zwei verschiedene Artikulationsorte handelt.

Manche würden derartige Verschleifungen als nachlässige Redeweise bewerten, auch wenn sie sie selbst benutzen, aber so funktioniert Sprache nun mal.

Comment: "Ich frage mich schon lange, ob es neben ich- und ach-Laut nicht noch weitere ch-Aussprachen gibt." Ja doch, den Loch-Laut. Also ob palatal [x] oder uvular [χ] macht einen hörbaren Unterschied, zumal χ in der IPA-Tabelle das stimmlose Gegenstück zu [ʁ] ist, so dass man *trocken* gelegentlich als *tχocken* hören kann (wobei Verwechslung ausgeschlossen, weil ch im Anlaut nicht gegeben ist).

Comment: Ah ja, war mir nicht bewusst, aber stimmt - für mich ein guter Hinweis!

Answer (score 1):

In standard High German it is /fʊʁçt/ in one complex syllable with the coda as in *Kirche* /ˈkɪʁçə/. Adding a little [ɪ] (as in *fam'ly*) will at least not hurt your comprehension, if stress remains on the first syllable nucleus.

Phonologically, we might speak of the underlying consonant phonemes /r/ and /x/, standardly realised with the phones [ʁ] (stimmhafter uvularer Frikativ) and [ç] (stimmloser palataler Frikativ) in a predictable distribution with allophones, first of all [r] in Southern German (stimmhafter alveolarer Vibrant) and [ʀ] eg. in Bühnendeutsch (stimmhafter uvularer Vibrant) or [ə] (Schwa).

This allows to infer two related conclusions.

First, [ç] is marking an exception to the general rule of [ç] after *i*, *e* and Umlaut (hence *ich*) and [x] after *a, o* and *u* (hence *Loch*). The intervening uvular in *Furcht* is assimilating the palatal fricative. The outcome can only be predictable if we ignore the first rule. If you mispredict this, you will find it hard to hear.

Second, [ʁç] has to be treated as a cluster. /r/ in syllable final position is standardly elided to *schwa*, thus *er-klä-r-en /ɛɐ̯ˈklɛːʁən/, same as in English *-er(s)* > *-a(s)*. Indeed we can find "füächtalich" spelled in eye-dialect. Problem then is that *ch* was not allowed in syllable onsets (hence sometimes *Kirsche* "church"). So it is technically impermissable.

We might therefore expect any combination of [ʁ], [r], [ʀ] and [ç] or [x], to say the least. And it is not easily predictable because if [x] is close to [⁠χ] (Stimmloser uvularer Frikativ) the cluster is distinguished only by a subset of the presented features (voice, place of articulation or manner), so dissimilation to a voiced trill may be preferable. Whatever the solution is, it might suggest itself as a syllable onset, allowing a second nucleus in the sonorant hierarchy, resulting in a bimoraic shape. Since r is voiced, this can happen fairly quickly.

While another solution is needed, because the etymology is unresolved (DWDS, nothing newer that I know of), it should be noted that *füach-t* does after all not invalidate any of the rules, if *-t* is taken as a formant (see eg. *Kehrricht*, "mit unorganisch angefügtem *-t* (wie bei *Obst*, s. d.) neben entwicklungsgeschichtlich älterem *kerach* (15. Jh.), *kehrich* (16. Jh.)", *kehren* "setzt germ. *karjan voraus", DWDS/Pfeifer). Chances are so this has to be from Northern German such as *burch* beside *Burg, buəg* (cf. *Magdeburg*ians notoriously stressing their name), not unlike English *borough*. It should also be noted that *fühürchterlich* is the only allowable form when talking about ghosts (*boo-hoo*) – indicating where the *stress* is situated, though it could be effective on the complex cluster, ca. *fürrrchterlich*(?).

I'd like to add that Greek *phobus* ("fear") and *terror* ("fear") are remotely plausible comparanda, accepting that German f is unlikely to be from **bʰegʷ* (cp. Latin *fugo* "flee"), or from *fR* < *dhR* (as is sporadic in Gothic).

tl;dr: don't confuse *Kirche* and *kehrrich(t)*. /faden

PS: "füachtalich", not "füächtalich" as I wrote. However, the noun is not easily quotable to that effect that is making the comparison doubtful.

Comment: Ich fände es schön, wenn du deine Antwort in deutscher Sprache verfasst hättest. Die Frage ist ja auch auf Deutsch gestellt.

Comment: Ja war ein Versehen. Ich werd's jetzt nicht extra übersetzen.