# Aussprache von CH nach R (durch, Arche, Kirche, ...)

Tags: pronunciation, austrian

In einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/73747/1487) wurde gefragt, wie das R im Wort *»Furcht«* auszusprechen sei. In [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73750/1487) habe ich zwar die gestellte Frage beantwortet, bin dann aber in den Kommentaren auf einen Fehler aufmerksam gemacht worden, den ich wiederum gemacht habe, weil ich von einer Aussprache des Digrams CH im Wort *»Furcht«* ausgegangen bin, die anders ist als in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Furcht) und [theFreeDictionary](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/Furcht) angegeben. Daher frage ich nun:

#### Wie wird das Digram CH im Wort *»Furcht«* und in anderen Wörtern, in denen CH nach R kommt, ausgesprochen?

Zur Auswahl stehen eigentlich nur zwei Laute:

- [ç] wie im Wort *»ich«* (ich-CH)
- [x] wie im Wort *»ach«* (ach-CH)

In Wiktionary finde ich unter anderem diese Einträge:

- [durch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/durch) = [dʊʁç]
- [Furcht](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Furcht) = [fʊʁçt]
- [Furche](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Furche) = [ˈfʊʁçə]
- [Lurch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lurch) = [lʊʁç]

Bei keinem dieser vier Wörter ist eine alternative Aussprache angegeben, und das trifft auch auf alle davon abgeleiteten Wörter zu (*dadurch, furchtbar, furchen, Froschlurch, ...*). Wiktionary ist also sehr eindeutig und legt sich auf das ich-CH fest.

Ich hingegen höre in diesem Wörtern das ach-CH, also [dʊʁx], [fʊʁxt], [ˈfʊʁxə] und  [lʊʁx].

Ich muss dazusagen, dass ich im Osten Österreichs aufgewachsen bin und dort seit nunmehr 58 Jahren auch lebe (geboren 1965 in Graz, ab 1996 in Wien, seit 2016 in St. Pölten), und unter der eingangs verlinkten Antwort hat ein User (Dodezv) diesen Kommentar hinterlassen:

> Für mich ist ein wichtiges Erkennungsmerkmal für Sprecher aus der
> Region von Österreichisch/Bairisch, dass sie nach "r" "ch" wie in [x]
> statt wie der Rest Deutschlands mit [ç] sprechen. Ich dachte, dieser
> Unterschied wäre weithin bekannt.

Mir war dieser Unterschied nicht bekannt, und Wiktionary weiß offenbar auch nichts davon, denn bei vielen anderen Wörtern, die im [österreichischen Standarddeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch) anders ausgesprochen werden als im [deutschen Standarddeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesdeutsches_Hochdeutsch), ist dieser Unterschied sehr wohl angegeben ([Kaffee](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kaffee), [Mathematik](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mathematik), [Portier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Portier), [Tabak](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tabak) ...)

Ich glaube sehr gern, dass CH in Regionen, in denen bairische Dialekte beheimatet sind (also u.a. in fast ganz Österreich) nach R als [x] ausgesprochen wird, während in anderen deutschsprachigen Regionen der Laut [ç] verwendet wird. Aber meiner Beobachtung nach kann das nur die halbe Wahrheit sein.

Hier sind Beispiele mit anderen Vokalen als U vor RCH. Bei diesen Vokalen höre ich auch hier in Österreich den Laut [ç]:

- **ARCH**

  - [Archiv](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Archiv) = [aʁˈçiːf]
  - [Monarchie](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Monarchie) = [monaʁˈçiː]
  - [Archäologie](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Arch%C3%A4ologie) = [aʁçɛoloˈɡiː]
  - [Arche](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Arche) = [ˈaʁçə]
  - [schnarchen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schnarchen) = [ˈʃnaʁçn̩]
- **IRCH**

  - [Kirche](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kirche) = [ˈkɪʁçə]
- **ERCH** und **ÄRCH**

  - [Lerche](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lerche) und [Lärche](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/L%C3%A4rche) = [ˈlɛʁçə]
  - [Zwerchfell](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zwerchfell) = [ˈt͡svɛʁçˌfɛl]
  - [Pferch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pferch) = [p͡fɛʁç]

Bei den folgenden Lauten höre ich aber denselben Laut, den ich auch im Wort *Furcht* wahrnehme, nämlich [x]:

- **ORCH**

  - [Schnorchel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schnorchel) = [ˈʃnɔʁçl̩] - [ˈʃnɔʁxl̩]
  - [Morchel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Morchel) = [ˈmɔʁçl̩] - [ˈmɔʁxl̩]
  - [horchen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/horchen) = [ˈhɔʁçn̩] - [ˈhɔʁxn̩]
  - [Storch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Storch) = [ʃtɔʁç] - [ʃtɔʁx]
- **ÖRCH**

  - [Störche](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/St%C3%B6rche) = [ˈʃtœʁçə] - [ˈʃtœʁxə]
- **ÜRCH**

  - [fürchten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%BCrchten) = [ˈfʏʁçtn̩] - [ˈfʏʁxtn̩]

Kann es sein, dass in Regionen, in denen bairische Dialekte heimisch sind (Österreich, Bayern) der Vokal vor dem R auf den nachfolgenden CH-Laut wirkt, während das sonstwo nicht der Fall ist?

Mir ist bekannt, dass Vokale sich auf die Färbung der davor stehenden Konsonanten auswirken. Achte auf den Klang des SCH in *»Schi«* und *»Schuh«* (auch, aber etwas schwächer: *»Stier« - »stur«* und sogar *»Strick« - Strumpf«*.) Ich nehme den Unterschied zwischen *»Schi«* und *»Schuh«* fast so deutlich wahr wie den Unterschied der beiden CH-Laute zwischen *»ich«* und *»ach«.* Kann es sein, dass die Vokale auch über das R hinweg den Laut des nachfolgenden CH verändern?

Was mir auch auffällt:

Direkt nach Ü und Ö spricht man auch in Österreich den Laut [ç] (*Küche, nüchtern, Köche, höchst*), nach ÜR und ÖR nehme ich aber [x] wahr (*fürchten, Störche*), wobei es eigentlich korrekter wäre zu sagen, dass ich einen Laut höre, der zwischen [ç] und [x] liegt, den ich aber näher bei [x] als bei [ç] verorte.

Bei ACH und ARCH ist es hingegen genau andersrum. Direkt auf A folgt auch in Österreich das ach-CH [x] (ach, Dach, Bach). Auf AR folgt aber in ebenfalls im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum das ich-CH [ç] (Archiv, Arche, schnarchen). Hier setzt sich auch in Österreich der Laut [x] nicht über das R hinweg durch.

Insgesamt erscheint mir die Situation sehr verworren, und ich muss dabei auch zugeben, dass ich mir in manchen Fällen auch nicht ganz sicher bin, ob ich den Reibelaut in dem Kontinuum zwischen dem [stimmlosen palatalen Frikativ [ç]](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmloser_palataler_Frikativ) und dem [stimmlosen velaren Frikativ [x]](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmloser_velarer_Frikativ) immer auf der richtigen Seite wahrnehme.

Comment: Es könnte relevant sein, wie ch im regionalen Dialekt (im Gegensatz zum Österreichischen Standarddeutsch) ausgesprochen wird. Wenn ich als Norddeutscher versuche [fʊʁxt] zu sagen, fühle mich an Parodien von Hitlers Reden erinnert. Eventuell auch relevant: ["(In einigen süddeutschen Varietäten wie dem Schweizerdeutschen wird jedoch jedes ch in den genannten Fällen als ​[⁠x⁠]​ oder ​[⁠χ⁠]​ ausgesprochen.)"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(Digraph))

Comment: @Roland: Wir Ösis verdängen das gerne, aber Hitler war halt leider Österreicher. Er selbst wurde in Braunau am Inn als Sohn von Alois Hitler (Zollbeamter, der wegen seines Berufs in Braunau lebte) und Klara Hitler (geb. Pölzl) geboren. Alois und Klara, sowie deren Vorfahren stammten aber alle aus der Umgebung von Zwettl im Waldviertel in Niederösterreich. Daher ist davon auszugehen, dass Adolfs Eltern auch in Braunau einen Waldviertler Dialekt gesprochen haben. Da Adolf in Oberösterreich aufwuchs, gibt es aber natürlich auch starke Einflüsse aus diesem Bundesland auf seine Sprechweise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich habe eine Karte gefunden: [Ch nach R](https://prowiki.ids-mannheim.de/bin/view/AADG/ChnachR).
Danach

1. gibt es wirklich ein Unterschied beim vorangehenden Vokal
2. sind Österreicher (auch innerhalb der Bundesländer) gespalten, es gibt nicht eine vorherrschende Variante
3. ragt das Phänomen, z.B. bei *durchaus* tief nach Bayern hinein

Unten die ursprüngliche Antwort:

#### Eigentlich in Österreich immer [x]...?

Ich habe zu diesem Thema eine Diplomarbeit gefunden: ["Ach, ich und die /r/-Vokalisierung" von Tina Hildebrandt(2013)](https://utheses.univie.ac.at/detail/26237).
Zu Standarddeutsch steht:

> The Standard German pattern for this allophony is [straight]forward and entirely predictable. [x]
> appears after back vowels, [ç] everywhere else.

Also hat (deutsches) Standarddeutsch immer [ç] nach /r/. Das deckt sich auch mit meiner Aussprache (Frankfurt/M).

Österreichisches Standarddeutsch (SAG) hat, wie bekannt, keine offizielle Aussprache. Südbairisch (also z.B. Tirol) kennt überhaupt kein [ç], aber für SAG ist ohnehin Mittelbairisch ausschlaggebend.
Für die Aussprache im Österreichischen wird angegeben:

> Luick (1932) already noted that 'we' in Austria have a uvular fricative, contrary the notion of
> pronouncing the palatal [ç] after /r/, /l/ and /n/.
>
> > nach r, l, n wie in Kirche, Storch, Kelch, manch immer palatal, während wir nach r
> > gutturalen Laut haben. (Luick 1932:98)

Auffällig: Das klingt sehr stark danach, dass zumindest Luick auch in "Kirche" noch [x] hatte. (Sonst hätte er es ja wohl nicht als Beispiel genommen.)
Aber die Aussprache in Österreich ist natürlich stark von der Aussprache in Deutschland beeinflusst. Das gilt dann umso mehr für eher gelernte oder seltenere Wörter wie "Monarchie".

Viel mehr als das habe ich nicht gefunden, die Quellenlage über das Phänomen ist sehr dünn.

##### Sichtung auf Youtube

Ich habe über die Seite [filmot.com](https://filmot.com/search/Furcht/NU-jkxxWTj8/1?&country=195) Youtube-Untertitel auf das Wort "Furcht" durchsucht.

In Beiträgen des Bayerischen Rundfunks sprechen fast alle Sprecher, auch die mit dialektaler Färbung, [ç].
In Videos aus Österreich sprechen fast alle Sprecher [x].
Das gleiche gilt auch für "Kirche", auch nur [x].

##### Nicht-Ergebnisse der Recherche

- Nirgendwo wird ein Pattern beschrieben, das zusätzlich von dem Vokal vor dem "r" abhängt, wie der Fragesteller beschreibt.
- Über Bayern habe ich nichts gefunden.
- Der [Atlas Alltagssprache](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de) hat keinen Eintrag für ein Wort mit "rch".
- [Hall](https://langsci-press.org/catalog/book/331), eines der ersten Ergebnisse, beschäftigt sich viel mit der Alternation zwischen [x] und [ç], aber in deutschen Dialekten, nicht Varianten des Standarddeutschen.
- Viel Literatur beschäftigt sich mit fundamentalen Fragen wie "Gibt es zwei Phoneme /x/ und /ç/ oder nur eines?", in dieser ist der Istzustand meist nicht sehr ausführlich beschrieben.

Comment: Eines der charakteristischen Merkmale von Südbairisch (=Alpenbairisch) ist die auffallend "harte" gutturale Aussprache von CH. Es ist richtig, dass man in diesen Gegenden kaum ein [ç] hört, stattdessen hört man dort [x] und vor allem [χ]. (*»Wie sagt der Tiroler zur Banane? - BananeKCH«*). Diese Variante wird in Österreich in Tirol, Kärnten und den drei südlichen Gauen Salzburgs gesprochen, dort leben ca. 15% aller Österreicher. In Vorarlberg (mit weniger als 5% aller Österreicher) werden alemannische Dialekte gesprochen. Die restlichen Einwohner Österreichs (das sind ca. 80%) leben ...

Comment: ... in Gegenden, in denen Mittelbairisch (=Donaubairisch) gesprochen wird. Diese große Mehrheit bestimmt die "offizielle" Aussprache des österreichischen Standarddeutsch, die im Übrigen genauso inoffiziell ist wie die "offizielle" Aussprache des deutschländischen Standarddeutsch, denn weder da noch dort gibt es eine Behörde, die eine "offizielle" Aussprache definieren könnte. Obendrein ist die tatsächliche Aussprache innerhalb Deutschlands sogar stärker divers als innerhalb Österreichs, weswegen es in Deutschland sogar schwieriger wäre, eine "offizielle" Aussprache zu definieren als in ...

Comment: ... Österreich. (Vergleiche Sprecher aus Saarbrücken, Aachen, Emden, Prenzlau, Bautzen, Rosenheim, Konstanz und Göttingen.) Die Videos muss ich mir erst anhören, aber wenn dort unter den österreichischen Sprechern zufällig viele aus dem südbairisch-sprachigen Raum sind, ist der Befund, dass dort *»Kirche«* mit [x] gesprochen wird, leider ein anekdotischer und daher nicht viel wert. Ich vermute, dass diese Fragestellung bisher noch nicht wissenschaftlich untersucht wurde. Vielleicht fühlt sich ein Germanist berufen, darüber mal einen Artikel zu schreiben.

Answer (score 1):

Ich zweifle, ob die von dir beschriebene Variation zwischen palatalem [rç] und velarem [rx] wirklich von der Qualität des vorangehenden Vokals beeinflusst ist.

### Zweifel am Einfluss der Vokalqualität

Die Variation zwischen palatalem [ç] und velarem [x] in der ursprünglich norddeutschen Standardaussprache richtet sich nach der Anteriorität des vorangehenden Vokals (vorne–hinten). Nach vorderen Vokalen ist die Aussprache palatal [ç], nach hinteren Vokalen ist sie verlar [x]:

|  | Vorne: ç | Hinten: x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Geschlossen | ɪç, ʏç | ʊx |
| Mittel | ɛç, œç | ɔx |
| Offen |  | ax |

Wenn hingegen bei deinen Beispielen für die Variation zwischen palatalem [rç] und velarem [rx] ebenfalls die Qualität des vorangehenden Vokals den Ausschlag gäbe, dann käme es nicht auf die Anteriorität an (vorne–hinten), sondern auf die Rundung. Nach ungerundeten Vokalen wäre die Aussprache palatal [rç], nach gerundeten Vokalen velar [rx]:

|  | Ungerundet: rç | Gerundet: rx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Geschlossen | ɪrç | ʏrx, ʊrx |
| Mittel | ɛrç | œrx, ɔrx |
| Offen | arç |  |

Es dünkt mich jedoch aus zwei Gründen unwahrscheinlich, dass die Rundung den Ausschlag gibt:

1. Es ist phonetisch gesehen nicht plausibel, dass die Rundung eine Rolle spielt. Die Laute [ç] und [x] unterscheiden sich in der Anteriorität (vorne–hinten), und nicht in der Rundung.
2. Es ist nicht plausibel, dass dieselbe Variation zwischen palatelem [ç] und velarem [x] von zwei unterschiedlichen Merkmalen des vorangehenden Vokals abhängt, je nachdem, ob ein [r] dazwischentritt oder nicht.

Aber wie lässt sich die von dir beschriebene Variation denn sonst erklären?

### Sprachwandel-Hypothese

Meine Vermutung wäre die, dass hier ein Sprachwandel im Gang ist. Ich gehe davon aus, dass ursprünglich im mittelbairischem Raum die Aussprache von RCH stets velar gewesen ist [rx]. Die Erklärung, die ich dafür im Kopf habe (ich erinnere mich leider nicht mehr, woher), ist die folgende: [r] wird vokalisiert zum hinteren Vokal [a], und nach hinteren Vokalen wird CH als [x] ausgesprochen. Seit einigen Generationen steigt jedoch der Einfluss der modernen Standardaussprache, in der die Aussprache von RCH stets palatal ist [rç]. In einem Prozess, der zur Zeit noch in Gang ist, kommen also allmählich auch palatale Aussprachen [rç] in einem Gebiet vor, wo früher nur die velare Aussprache verbreitet war [rx]. Da der Prozess noch in Gang ist, besteht zur Zeit eine gewisse Variation und Unsicherheit. Ob die Aussprache palatal [rç] oder velar [rx] ist, variiert also von Ort zu Ort, von Person zu Person, oder von Wort zu Wort.

Diese Sprachwandelhypothese passt gut zusammen mit dem Befund aus der von Dodezv angeführten Karte [CH nach R • AADG](https://prowiki.ids-mannheim.de/bin/view/AADG/ChnachR). An vielen Orten in Bayern und Österreich besteht eine Variation zwischen palataler und velarer Aussprache, wobei die velare Aussprache [rx] durchaus auch nach ungerundetem Vokal vorkommt («Architekt», «Kirche»). Leider hat es kein Beispiel mit vorderem gerundeten Vokal. (Übrigens ist anzumerken, dass es im [AADG](https://prowiki.ids-mannheim.de/bin/view/AADG) nicht um Dialekte geht, sondern um die Standardsprache bzw. die «Vorlesesprache von Oberstufenschülern».)

Falls die Sprachwandelhypothese stimmt, so ist es bloss ein Zufall, dass in deinen Beispielen die Aussprache von CH von der Rundung des vorangehenden Vokals abzuhängen scheint. Es wäre also zu erwarten, dass in deiner eigenen Sprache oder in der Sprache von anderen Leuten an deinem Ort auch Gegenbeispiele vorkommen, etwa palatales [rç] nach vorderen gerundeten Vokalen in anderen Wörtern.

Comment: Was mache ich denn nun? Ich habe hier zwei außergewöhnlich gute Antworten, die ich beide akzeptieren und dadurch mit 15 Punkten belohnen möchte. Aber nachdem ich Dodezv die schon vergebenen 15 Punkte nicht wieder wegnehmen will, kann ich dir nur feierlich den unsichtbaren Wanderpokal für ausgezeichnete aber unterbewertete Antworten überreichen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Haha, völlig richtig! Man könnte es aber auch so sehen, dass es auf die Frage hinausläuft, was du höher bewertest: das ausführliche Quellen-Zusammentragen oder den gewagten Interpretationsversuch?

Comment: Zum Inhalt deiner Antwort: In Österreich findet seit ca. 30-40 Jahren (seit dem Aufkommen von Satellitenfernsehen, danach verstärkt durch das Internet) ein ziemlich extremer Sprachwandel statt, der sich darin manifestiert, dass junge Sprecher eine ganz andere Sprache sprechen als ältere. Damit meine ich nicht die übliche Jugendsprache, die man mit dem Ende der Pubertät wieder weitgehend ablegt, sondern ich meine einen grundlegenden Wechsel. Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (also auch in Deutschland) werden kaum noch Dialekte gesprochen. Ich war Ende April eine Woche lang in Stuttgart und ...

Comment: ... habe dort auf der Straße kein einziges Wort Schwäbisch gehört, ebenso hört man in Wien kaum noch ein Wort Wiener Dialekt. Das Einzige, was man noch hört, ist eine regionale Färbung, hauptsächlich bei Vokalen und sonoren Konsonanten, und das auch nur bei älteren Sprechern. In den 1980er-Jahren war Austropop eine sehr beliebte Musikrichtung in Österreich. Das sind Lieder, die bevorzugt im Dialekt gesungen wurden (»Schifoan« von Ambros, »I wü ham noch Fürstenfeld« von STS) und die wochenlang in den Top-Rängen der österreichischen Charts lagen, nicht zuletzt auch, weil sie in genau der ...

Comment: ... Sprache gesungen wurden, die die Jugend damals gesprochen hat. Heutige Kinder und Jugendliche verstehen diese Texte aber mehrheitlich nicht mehr. Innerhalb nur einer Generation sind Dialekte fast vollständig verschwunden. In Österreich verwenden junge Sprecher heute bevorzugt eine Sprache, die sie von Influencern aus diversen Sozial-Media-Kanälen kennen. Und die kommen entweder ohnehin aus Deutschland, oder sie sprechen ein Deutsch, das dem in Deutschland gesprochenem entspricht. (Wer österreichisches Deutsch spricht, wird in Deutschland nicht als Influencer akzeptiert und ist dadurch ...

Comment: ... im gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum nicht erfolgreich.) Die Folge davon ist, dass das österreichische Deutsch mit einem atemberaubenden Tempo zuerst aus der Öffentlichkeit und dann auch aus privaten Räumen verschwindet. Die Dialekte sind schon so gut wie weg, die deutschländische Grammatik wird in Österreich schon längst als gleichwertig oder meist sogar bessere Version gegenüber der österreichischen angesehen, und auch Austriazismen verschwinden schön langsam aus Österreich. (In Supermärkten findet man fast keine Paradeiser und Erdäpfel mehr, stattdessen nur mehr Tomaten und Kartoffeln.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Aha, dann dünkt dich also die Sprachwandel-Hypothese gar nicht gewagt. Ich hatte noch nicht davon gehört, dass die Sprache in Österreich sich derart am Wandeln sei. Trotzdem gehst du zu weit mit der Aussage: «Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (also auch in Deutschland) werden kaum noch Dialekte gesprochen». Hier im anderen Alpenland herrscht der Dialekt so unangefochten vor wie eh und je seit den 30er Jahren.